# Flutter_Beacon Library sample app doesn't detect iBeacons Konkat

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

The repo for the sample app is the master branch here: https://github.com/alann-maulana/flutter_beacon.

I'm trying to change the UUID to scan the beacon I have, Konkat beacon, in flutter.
where should I change the UUID ?
or how can I scan this kind of beacons in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

On Android, unlike iOS, you are able to scan for all beacons regardless of Proximity UUID.  The Flutter beacon app you mention sets up Android beacon scanning  with a wildcard Region to match all beacons regardless of UUID.  So you do not need to change the UUID in the app to detect on Android.

If the app is not detecting, there may be a number of causes.  I wrote a list of things to check in the docs for the native Android Beacon Library which the Flutter app you mention uses under the hood on Android:

https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/detection-trouble.html